# Realtime data streaming with react native and BLE: Possible and/or how performant?

Tags: real-time, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native

I am a medical student working this summer to create a wearable device for children with cerebral palsy. The device should be capable of streaming via bluetooth LE to ios or android app, and I am hoping to have two bluetooth capable sensors each streaming (realtime) data samples (size: 3 float values per sample)  at around 50 Hz (or the highest frequency possible). I do see that there is a react native library for BLE (https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager), however I am concerned that I may run into performance issues if I go the route of developing with react native instead of native ios/android. Could you please either explain what route you think is best or link me some resources which may help?  Main questions I have are 1. Is this possible? 2. What BLE library do you recommend 3. Will I be sacrificing on BLE real time data streaming performance by going with react native? THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: I haven't heard of any bluetooth stream apis for react native, so far. Would regular scans work the same way for your device idea? If so, I believe ble-manager will answer to your needs.
I've previously used react-native-ibeacon, which also works by scan intervals, but there's no way to read custom data, as you need.

Comment: @RenatoBack Thank you for your message. Could you please elaborate on the method of using regular scans and/or scan intervals? I am not familiar with that

Comment: While streaming has a "permanent" connection, regular scans are like a radar. They run for a period in certain intervals. Something like: "listen to devices for 1 second and repeat it every 9 seconds". Which would give you nine "1 second" scans per minute, if my math is not wrong. That's just an example, in real life it could be 100 ms listening in every second.

Comment: @RenatoBack Thankyou. Do you know how frequently I could get data samples in that scenario? Research standard is 120hz and I am hoping to get as close as this as possible

Comment: We're starting to walk into unknown territory, here. At least to me. However, I found some interesting links about [iphone serial communication](http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2012/Nov/msg00065.html) and another plugin, [react-native-bluetooth-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-serial), which might do the trick. I haven't dealt with it, though.